# How to use select data from a table, make calculations and then updating new data into another table with same primary key as first?

Tags: java, mysql

I am using java servlet to do the following:

I have table called Table1 with two columns, "EmployeeID(Primary key)" and "Gross salary"

I have another table called Table2 with two columns, "EmployeeID(Primary key)" and "Net salary"

There are many employee IDs currently in the database.

How can I retrieve the Gross salary from Table1 for all employees, do calculations to calculate the net salary, and then insert the new value (after calculations) into Net salary in Table2, in the corresponding row for each employee?

This is what I have so far, may not even be on the right track, help is appreciated, thanks.

By the way, if any of you can please demonstrate an answer with the calculation part, for argument's sake, let netSalary = grossSalary - 100  as an example.

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Gross salary from payroll_system.Table1");
            ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to execute the query, not an update, then save your data in a HashMap, finally perform the calculations and insert the results:

```
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(selectSQL );
    Map<Integer, Float> grossSalaries = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Float> netSalaries = new HashMap<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        grossSalaries.put(rs.getInt(1), rs.getFloat(2));    
    }
    //Do the calculations for each one of the elements in the map
    //Save them into the netSalaries Map.

    //Then insert the rows in the Table2
    for(Integer key : netSalaries.keySet){
         String insertSt = "insert into Table2 values (?,?)";
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertSt);
         preparedStatement.setInt(1, key);
         preparedStatement.setFloat(2, netSalaries.get(key));
    }
```

Comment: Hi, can you please give an example with the calculations, thanks :) Just say for example netSalary = GrossSalary - 100. How to do this?

Comment: `for(Integer key : grossSalaries.keySet){
      float calc = grossSalaries.get(key) - 100; //
      netSalaries.put(key, calc);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should not have space in column name. 
E.g, use `"GrossSalary"` instead of `"Gross salary"`

If you want to **update an existing row** in Table2, say for `EmployeeID = 1`

```
UPDATE table2 t2 
JOIN table1 t1 
ON t2.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID
SET t2.NetSalary = t1.GrossSalary-100 
WHERE t1.EmployeeID = 1;
```

If you want to **insert a new row** into Table2, say for `EmployeeID = 1`

```
INSERT INTO table2(EmployeeID, NetSalary)
SELECT EmployeeID, GrossSalary-100 FROM table1
WHERE EmployeeID = 1;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But how do I perform this for all employees in the table (there could be 100 or more).

Comment: you can change the WHERE clause, such as `WHERE EmployeeID > 1;` or `WHERE EmployeeID BETWEEN 10 AND 20;` Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp. Please vote if you see my answer helpful.